# Error in React component causing app to re-render, which is causing infinite loop. Why?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-apollo, apollo-client

Without including code yet, I am wondering if anyone has ran into an issue where you:

- Have a component which is wrapped in `connect` and, in my case `apollo-client`
- Have child components also wrapped in `connect` that do a dispatch in `componentWillMount`
- Throw an error in a child component
- Get an infinite loop

The situation I am in is that any child that throws an error causes the parent component to run `render` again and all children seem to run `componentWillMount`, but do not run `componentWillUnmount`.

The error is not logged and does not appear in the console until the call stack overflows.

This causes them to all re-connect to Redux, dispatch the action as well as throw the error again because they are mounting again, which causes the loop.

I can try to repro, but that will take quite a bit of time, just wondering if someone has run into a similar issue that could offer somewhere to look.

Comment: Haven't used Apollo and can't say I recognize the problem. But for debugging purposes I would probably try to do some check inside `componentWillMount`  before dispatching the action again, and see if I could break the loop  and hope that the error wouldn't get lost that way. Or use breakpoints in `componentWillMount`  so that you can stop it any time you want.   And use tools like Redux devtools to see what actions have been dispatched and if they contain the expected payload etc.    https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension

Answer (score 1):

You should not be dispatching any actions in componentWillMount. Anything that is considered mutable should be done in componentDidMount. componentWillMount is similar to a constructor. The component hasn't mounted. The component is unaware of any state (unless you specify) but that state is not fulfilled until the component actually mounts, which happens in componentDidMount. Ideally, you should stick to the constructor and not really use componentWillMount. For any API calls or dispatching, you should keep those in cDM

Comment: Without seeing any code, I can't give you the best answer. What I said above is still true but that will probably only solve a portion of your problem. Also, for reference, React actually documents this as well. Try cross-referencing this with componentDidMount, found a little further down on that page.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Answer (score 0):

Clayton is right; `ComponentWillMount` is somewhat of an anti-pattern, despite having once been the way and the truth.  You probably want to use [`ComponentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

However, since you mentioned throwing, it's worth nothing that React 16 has a [`componentDidCatch` lifecycle hook](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html#introducing-error-boundaries).  This allows you to catch the error and handle it in react:

> Error boundaries are React components that catch JavaScript errors anywhere in their child component tree, log those errors, and display a fallback UI

In theory, this should allow you to handle the error and short-circuit `connect`.